# Setting up multiple instances of couchbase on fedora

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to setup multiple instance of couchbase (couchbase-server-enterprise-4.5.0-DP1-centos7.x86_64.rpm)in fedora OS 21 .

I am following the steps in the below URL to setup the multiple instances of couchdb.

```
[http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/rhel-multiple-instances.html][1]
```

I have completed the first steps and able to launch couchbase in the http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html.

I have installed couchbase only once. Is it fine or do I need to install one more instance.

I am not sure how to proceed from step 2 onwards.

If I don't create any user defined ports in /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config, will it be a problem?

I have setup nofile parameter as below in /etc/security/limits.conf file as mentioned in step 2.

Also, in the step 4 it is mentioned that, there is only one /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config file. How can I setp different short_name parameter in that file.

How , once instance of couchbase identifies another instance of couchbase?

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase really is much happier, and you will be too, to be on it's own OS, even if it is in something like Docker, VMs, etc. So I strongly recommend that you get something like Docker or VirtualBox to play with. Getting Couchbase to run multiple instances on the same OS is just not worth the hassle given the ease of other tools like I already mentioned.

That said, for development purposes, one of the best things about Couchbase is that you can develop on one node of Couchbase, but deploy against a much larger production cluster even with Multi-Dimensional Scaling enabled. It works very very well.